# How can I query range prometheus increase group by time step?

Tags: prometheus

I have a counter in prometheus .it always increases.I want to get the growth rate over time
i use query_range get this data

```
query_range?query=sum(msf_nginx_http_requests_total{msf_cluster="cluster01", msf_service =~ "api-apm-apm-cluster01"})&start=1649916044.036&end=1649919644.036&step=120
```

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {},
                "values": [
                    [
                        1649916044.036,
                        "4576235"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916164.036,
                        "4576707"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916284.036,
                        "4577098"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916404.036,
                        "4577258"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916524.036,
                        "4577469"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916644.036,
                        "4577741"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916764.036,
                        "4577852"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916884.036,
                        "4578069"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get the increase in data for each time period compared to the previous time period.
but if use increase function ,i will get that data

```
query_range?query=sum(increase(msf_nginx_http_requests_total{msf_cluster="cluster01", msf_service =~ "api-apm-apm-cluster01"}[1h]))&start=1649916044.036&end=1649919644.036&step=120
```

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {},
                "values": [
                    [
                        1649916044.036,
                        "7621.03448275862"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916164.036,
                        "7721.379310344828"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916284.036,
                        "7925.172413793102"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916404.036,
                        "7878.620689655173"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916524.036,
                        "7897.241379310345"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916644.036,
                        "7986.206896551724"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916764.036,
                        "7878.620689655172"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I need to write a query statement?
i want get the data just like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {},
                "values": [
                    [
                        1649916044.036,
                        "10"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916164.036,
                        "8"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916284.036,
                        "9"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916404.036,
                        "5"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916524.036,
                        "2"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916644.036,
                        "11"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916764.036,
                        "8"
                    ],
                    [
                        1649916884.036,
                        "0"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The value of the next time period is the increment relative to the previous time interval